# How to inject a component into a component in Angular2?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

Here's a way to create a submenu using ng2-bootstrap.

```
<li dropdown>
    <a dropdownToggle></a>
    <ul dropdownMenu></ul>
</li>
```

I want to encapsulate it into my component like this:

```
<li wcAccountMenu dropdown>
</li>
```

And inside wcAccountMenu:

```
<a dropdownToggle></a>
<ul dropdownMenu></ul>
```

I still want final DOM to keep the original structure for CSS styles to work.

And then I have: Error: Template parse errors:↵No provider for DropdownDirective cause one of child directives inside wcAccountMenu requires dropdown but doesn't see it. Probably because wcAccountMenu is instantiated before dropdown.

Can I somehow create a dropdown directive in WcAccountMenuComponent so it can be resolved inside?

Comment: Please provide more code. Why don't you use a shared service instead to communicate between components instead of injecting a component into another? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: "But inside component I want a dropdown component to be available. " What is "component"? Please provide more code.